# Maintain the list size in a HashMap

Tags: arraylist, hashmap

We have a HashMap like below,

```
    HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>> hm = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>>();
```

1) When ever the key repeats, the value(Integer) has to be added into the arraylist.
2) If size of the arrayList size crosses threshold size, say 500, then remove the Kay:Value from the hashMap.

Apart from the usual approach of checking the size of arrayList before every put in the map, is there a better approach? Please advice.

Comment: Hi Sanket,
My thought so far, is brute force, like checking the size of the arrayList before every put and delete the key:value from hashMap if size has crossed the threshold, here it is 500.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using Guava's [`ListMultimap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ListMultimap.html).

```
ListMultimap<String, Integer> map = ArrayListMultimap.create();

for(...) {
    ...
    map.put(key, value);
    if (map.get(key).size() > 500)
        map.removeAll(key);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Leventov.. It was same which I'd thought. Wondering if any optimized way.